# Spinnaker - Pull artifact from Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, spinnaker

I have an Artifactory server which stores the build artifacts. I want Spinnaker to pull artifacts from it. When I am trying to do so, I am facing 401: Unauthorized error, but i have entered all the credentials correctly. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried performing the same steps Spinnaker's default packer template/script is performing, but outside of Spinnaker?

These are a couple of the relevant steps from the default template/script: https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/packer/install_packages.sh#L32 and https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/packer/install_packages.sh#L42

That is, shell into an ubuntu machine, add the artifactory repo you're trying to access as an apt source, and then try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install $YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME`.

Once you can successfully install the package without involving Spinnaker, you'll be in good shape to try the same thing with Spinnaker.

Thanks,
-Matt